# How to use a for-loop/range to end a specific character input in Python?

Tags: python

If user entered anything other than an integer it should be ignored, whereas, if it were to be an integer it should be added to the `lst` (list)

**the function should display the list of integers, ignoring anything that wasn't an integer and display the max and min number.**

```
lst = []
n = int(input("Enter Integers: "))
for index in range(min(n), max(n)):
    if index == ' ':
        return
for i in range(min(n),max(n)):
    elements = int(input())
    lst.append(elements)
print(lst)
print(len(lst))
for num in lst:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num, end= ' ')
```

I have a function here that prompts users to enter a list of integers, if SPACE is inputted: it should END the input.

I'm quite new at python and not sure how to go about this code.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
input("Enter Integers: ")
```

evaluates to a string. Since you want to read strings until a space is inserted, you need a infinite loop:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter an integer: ")
```

If the user provides a space, stop reading numbers:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter an integer: ")

    if value == ' ':
        # Exit the loop
        break
```

If you want to convert it to an integer, use the `int` function and append it to `numbers`:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter an integer: ")

    if value == ' ':
        break

    numbers.append(int(value))
```

You can also add a validation, if the user provides a value that isn't a number:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter an integer: ")

    if value == ' ':
        break

    try:
        number = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        print('The value is not a number!')
        # Continue looping
        continue

    numbers.append(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code there is somewhat misleading and adds confusion to the question. My solution below is based off the question before the code.

```
lst = []

print("Enter Integers:")

while True:
    n = input()
    try:
        # Try converting to an int, if can't ignore it
        lst.append(int(n))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    # If space input, break the loop
    if n == ' ':
        break

print("Integer list: ")
print(lst) 
if len(lst) > 0:
    print("Min: " + str(min(lst)))
    print("Max: " + str(max(lst)))
```